# SQL Server 2014 DBCC CHECKDB notification

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to include the results of DBCC CHECKDB in the notification email sent to me. I have seen some techniques in older versions of SQL Server. Is there any new / easier way to due this in SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Consider looking at the free http://minionware.net/checkdb/ that can handle that stuff for you. Easier than trying to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a Job Step next to the DBCC CHECKDB Step, and set the Checkdb Step field 'On success action' to 'Go to Next Step'
2. In the Checkdb Step create an output file.
3. Now, in second Step use the log file to be sent as an email attachment using T-SQL

   - `exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @file_attachments = 'Path\Filename.txt'`

This should work fine. I am not aware of any inbuilt solution for this.

Comment: Just to add to your response: if I recall correctly, if you create a maintenance plan, you can configure that same info.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it on out test box and it works well. I did hit one snag with the permissions for the attachment. I know that it's permissions because I granted 'everyone' permissions to this directory and it succeeded.